# Formula's or symbols in footnotes using knitr and kableExtra

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, symbols, tabular

Does anyone know how to place a formula, a (weird) character, or words in italic within a sentence of a footnote of a table?

I'm creating a pdf file with Rmarkdown and kableExtra. But stuff like `$Y_{t-1}$` or `$p < .001$` (since I want the `p` to be italic) does not work. Or should I really learn xtable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The trick is **1.** to escape latex code and special characters four times, e.g. `\\\\frac`, **2.** to set option `escape=FALSE` in `footnote()`.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r tab}
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
df <- data.frame(v1=rnorm(6), v2=runif(6), v3=rbinom(6, 1, .33), 
                 row.names=LETTERS[1:6])
kable(df, "latex", align="c", booktabs=TRUE) %>%
footnote(general=c("$a^2+b^2=c^2,$",     
                   "$\\\\sigma^2=\\\\frac{1}{n-1}\\\\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\\\\bar{x})^2;$", 
                   "1,000 \\\\$;", "100\\\\%."),
         number=c("Hello\ there! \\\\textit{Hello\ there!}"),
         footnote_as_chunk=TRUE, 
         escape=FALSE)
```
````

**Yields:**
[image]

Comment: Many thanks, really nice of you, can you recommend some manual for Latex for R users?

Comment: `footnote()` is this a function of Latex? do i need to install a package for that?

Comment: Very welcome. A lot of stuff you can find here on Stack Overflow or at [TeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/). `footnote()` is a function of the `kableExtra` package which library you call with `library(kableExtra)` in code above. Perhaps you need to install it first with `install.packages(kableExtra)`.

Comment: I had installed kableExtra already, but appearantly i needed to reinstall it, because now it works beautifully! silly me.. i'm a slow learner.

Comment: Would you also know how to put symbols or Latex formulas within the table, I mean in one of the (table) cells so not the title or footnote?